# Where in jBoss when using SSL and JAAS are the Cache-Control and Pragma HTTP headers set?

Tags: uitableview, ssl, jboss, josso, no-cache

Implemented JAAS and SSL on jBoss 4.2.2 and found the issue with being unable to download .pdf's. after some poking around I found references to the Pragma: No-cache and Cache-Control: no-cache headers, and why that prevents IE from downloading .pdf's and related items.

Fine, I stuffed Cache-control, private and Pragma, "" in the header and situation handled.
But I'm looking for where in the expanse of jBoss source I would discover the offending code and the conditions that the original headers are created.

Yes, I have searched, just not well..

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Oops!

Its in Josso a method called prepareNonCacheResponse()

my mistake for not searching the whole hard drive.

Thanks,
So do I downvote my own question for being stupid?